# How to disable keyboard or WASD controls in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

How to disable the keyboard controls for the camera in the default scene?

```
<a-scene></a-scene>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `wasd-controls` component is attached to the default camera by default. You can either:

Define `<a-camera>` with `wasd-controls` disabled to override the default one:

```
<a-scene><a-camera wasd-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera></a-scene>
```

Or remove it with `removeAttribute` (when the scene is ready):

```
document.querySelector('[camera]').removeAttribute('wasd-controls');
```

Or define a raw camera without `wasd-controls`:

```
<a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls></a-entity>
```

Comment: this worked for me: ´camera.setAttribute("wasd-controls-enabled", false);´

Comment: I'm at 1.4.0 and this does not work; I also tried property: wasd-controls="adEnabled:false;wsEnabled:false" with no luck.

Comment: Oops.. turns out I had another camera.. wasd-controls-enabled="false" worked fine once I removed that 2nd camera.